# Updating fields in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, xataface

I have two tables as below:

```
Table A:
home_id; home_name; home_address

Table B:
person_id; person_name; home_id; home_name; home_address
```

I am using `xataface` to create a front page for my MySQL database. User will enter data at Table B, which provide person_name and home_id.

I want the home_name and home_address to be updated accordingly based on home_id entered in Table B, OR when information in Table A is updated. (i.e. user needs not enter anything at home_name and home_address in Table B)

Should I use trigger? Or should I use foreign key for that?

Comment: You could use the foreign keys along with cascading, however it could be bad design if you have to do it a lot.  Too many indexes will create a load during CRUD operations as all those indexes get updated.  I think transactions would be a better fit.

Comment: why are you using home_name,home_address column in Table B?

Comment: @Bit_hunter since the user don't understand what home_id means, they need to see home_name to know which home the person is going

Comment: @lokheart I think he is asking that because since you are using `home_id`, which is presumably a foreign key, there shouldn't be a real need to store those two pieces of information again.  You have the key so you can easily `JOIN` results in from Table A.

Comment: @Crackertastic yes, I understand what you mean, but in `xataface`, all they can see when editing the row is only a `home_id`, and I want the information linked from table A to be presented when they are editing table B.

Comment: You should change your table structure. Normalize your tables. Refer it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies




`Table A:
home_id; home_name; home_address



Table B:
person_id; person_name; home_id;`

Now update both tables using foreign key.

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with `xataface` at all.  If that is how they have you do it, so be it, but sounds like they are forcing you into bad DB design....

Answer (score 0):

First Normalize your tables:-

```
Table A:
home_id; home_name; home_address
```

Home_id is primary key

```
Table B: 
person_id; person_name; home_id;
```

Person_id is primary key & Home_id is foreign key.Home_id in Table B will be primary key of table A.

**Insert Records:-**

**Step 1.** Insert address first in Table A. It will generate unique Home_id.

**Step 2.** Now insert reocrd in Table B with uging newluy create home_id as foreign key.

**Update records:-**

**Table A.** Update table A on using unique Home_id

**Table B.** Update table B on using unique Person_id

**Table A & Table B.** 
Update both tables using two seperate update queries. But put both queries in a Transaction to maintain atomicity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

or use below query:-

```
UPDATE Table_B JOIN Table_A ON Table_A.home_id = Table_B.home_id
  SET Table_A.home_name=<home_name>,
      Table_A.home_address= <home_address>,
      Table_B.person_name=<person_name>
WHERE Table_B.person_id = <search_contidion>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here:

1. Use the afterSave() trigger for Table B to update the Table A values when B records are saved.

   ```
   function afterSave(Dataface_Record $record){
       df_q("replace into `Table B` (`home_id`,`home_name`,`home_address`) values (
       '".addslashes($record->val('home_id'))."',
       '".addslashes($record->val('home_name'))."',
       '".addslashes($record->val('home_address'))."');
   }
   ```
2. If Table A is just a calculated table and should never be edited directly by the user, then you could change Table A to a Dynamic Table that depends upon Table B. More on dynamic tables [here](http://xataface-tips.blogspot.ca/2014/06/improve-performance-of-calculated.html)

The DynamicTable definition would look something like:

```
$tbl = new DynamicTable(
    'TableA',
    array('CREATE TABLE TableA (
        home_id INT(11) not null primary key,
        home_name VARCHAR(100),
        home_address VARCHAR(255)',
      'INSERT INTO TableA (home_id, home_name, home_address) select home_id, home_name, home_address    from TableB'
    ),
    'TableB'
);

$tbl->update();
```

An appropriate place to put this code is in your beforeHandleRequest() method since that is called before each request, so it will ensure that the TableA data is always kept in sync with TableB when TableB changes.